# Center menu, center pictures, HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

Good morning. I'm new to html/css and to programming in general and this is my first post. Below is my current code. I'd like to do three things, that I'm currently unable to do:

1. to center the purple menu with the four boxes: I've tried to move the nav bar inside the header, but without success.
2. to put in a single line the card with red wine and white wine and below them, the other two. I've created two DIV parent directories, each with two childs.
3. to put the "comprar" (to  buy) button below each picture.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vinería Baco</title>
    <!--link css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./estilos.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <!--seccion hero/banner-->
    <header>
        <p><h1 class="h1_rojo">Vinería Baco</h1></p>
        <p><h2 class="h2_turquesa">El mejor vino de todo Berisso</h2></p>
    <!--Menu de navegacion-->
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="menu menu__item"><a href="./contacto.html">Contactanos</a></li>
          <li class="menu menu__item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/martin.prozapas">Facebook</a></li>
          <li class="menu menu__item"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/elonofficiall/?hl=es">Instagram</a></li>
          <li class="menu menu__item"><a href="./nosotros.html">Acerca de nosotros</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
      <!--Seccion main-->
      <main>
        <!--cards 1 to 2-->
        <div class="card1">
          <a href="./vino-tinto.html"><img alt="vino tinto" src="../img/tintos/tintos.jpg"width=150" height="70"></a><button type="button">Comprar</button><br>
          <a href="./vino-blanco.html"><img alt="vino blanco" src="../img/blancos/blancos.jpg"width=150" height="70"></a><button type="button">Comprar</button><br>  
        <!--cards 3 to 4-->
        <div class="card2">
          <a href="./vino-rosado.html"><img alt="vino rosado" src="../img/rosados/rosados.jpg"width=150" height="70"></a><button type="button">Comprar</button><br>
          <a href="./vino-especial.html"><img alt="vinos especiales" src="../img/especiales/especiales.jpg"width=150" height="70"></a><button type="button">Comprar</button><br></div>
      </main><br><br>
      <!--Seccion footer-->
      <footer>
        <h4>2021 | Hecho por MGP | 2021</h4>
      </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*HERO SECTION*/
/*Encabezados*/
.h1_turquesa {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#00868b;
  text-align: center;
}
.h1_rojo {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#8b0000;
  text-align: center;
}
.h1_azul {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:rgb(138, 43, 226);
  text-align: center;
}
.h1_verde {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(0, 128, 0);
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:rgb(139, 0, 139);
  text-align: center;
}
/*Párrafos*/
.parr {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
/*Fondo*/
body {
  background-color: rgb(197, 189, 170);
}
/*Imágenes*/
img {
    display: block;
    max-width:500px;
    max-height:500px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
/*MENU*/
.menu {
  background-color: rgb(175, 76, 122); 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.menu__item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
} 
/*MAIN*/
/*Card section*/
.card1{
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(197, 189, 170);
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
} 
.card2{
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(197, 189, 170);
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
} 
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; 
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
/*FOOTER*/
footer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 50px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would suggest running your code through a beautifier to clean up everything and you can see if you accidentally forgot to close a tag. In your instance, you forgot to close one of your div tags which I closed for you. I also nested both of your divs `card1` and `card2` into a `card-container`. I went ahead and flexed that div with and justified it to the center. I also added a `.flex` class to align your unordered list into the center. Please see those changes below. I am unsure what you mean about part 2 of your question, if you can please elaborate further.

```css
/*HERO SECTION*/
/*Encabezados*/
.h1_turquesa {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#00868b;
  text-align: center;
}
.h1_rojo {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#8b0000;
  text-align: center;
}
.h1_azul {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:rgb(138, 43, 226);
  text-align: center;
}
.h1_verde {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(0, 128, 0);
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:rgb(139, 0, 139);
  text-align: center;
}
/*Párrafos*/
.parr {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
/*Fondo*/
body {
  background-color: rgb(197, 189, 170);
}
/*Imágenes*/
img {
    display: block;
    max-width:500px;
    max-height:500px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
/*MENU*/
.menu {
  background-color: rgb(175, 76, 122); 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.menu__item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
} 
/*MAIN*/
/*Card section*/
.card1{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgb(197, 189, 170);
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
} 
.card2{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgb(197, 189, 170);
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
} 
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; 
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
/*FOOTER*/
footer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 50px 0px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vinería Baco</title>
    <!--link css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./estilos.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <!--seccion hero/banner-->
    <header>
        <p><h1 class="h1_rojo">Vinería Baco</h1></p>
        <p><h2 class="h2_turquesa">El mejor vino de todo Berisso</h2></p>
    <!--Menu de navegacion-->
      <nav>
        <ul class="flex">
          <li class="menu menu__item"><a href="./contacto.html">Contactanos</a></li>
          <li class="menu menu__item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/martin.prozapas">Facebook</a></li>
          <li class="menu menu__item"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/elonofficiall/?hl=es">Instagram</a></li>
          <li class="menu menu__item"><a href="./nosotros.html">Acerca de nosotros</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
      <!--Seccion main-->
      <main>
        <!--cards 1 to 2-->
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card1">
          <a href="./vino-tinto.html"><img alt="vino tinto" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x350/000/fff"width=150" height="70"></a><br><button type="button">Comprar</button><br>
          <a href="./vino-blanco.html"><img alt="vino blanco" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x350/000/fff" width=150" height="70"></a><br><button type="button">Comprar</button><br>  
        </div>
        <!--cards 3 to 4-->
        <div class="card2">
          <a href="./vino-rosado.html"><img alt="vino rosado" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x350/000/fff"width=150" height="70"></a><br><button type="button">Comprar</button><br>
          <a href="./vino-especial.html"><img alt="vinos especiales" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x350/000/fff"width=150" height="70"></a><br><button type="button">Comprar</button><br>
        </div>
      </main><br><br>      
      </div>

      <!--Seccion footer-->
      <footer>
        <h4>2021 | Hecho por MGP | 2021</h4>
      </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** inserted dummy images into HTML. It appears buttons are displaying below the images as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'm still unable to have even spaces between the four pictures. And the "comprar" button is aligned to the right, when it should be below. 
http://i.imgur.com/gKAXNX6.png

Comment: @martproz WITHOUT any CSS changes I inserted dummy images into your HTML. Buttons appear to be ***below*** images as expected. Please provide more code or fiddle that shows your issue. Look at my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/mtkL8jg4/4/). Also, make sure you copy my HTML into yours for the "new one". I added `<br>` elements between the img src and the `<button>`

Comment: thank you so much! I copied your html and now it looks very good!

Comment: thanks again! I can't yet upvote, as I'm still new.

Answer (score 0):

There's a mindset that always help me out.

> If you have problems positioning something, create a div parent.

I create as many div parents as needed.

For example:

```
<div>
   <div>My element 1</div>
   <div>My element 2</div>
   <div>My element 3</div>
   <div>My element 4</div>
</div>
```

Sometimes I might want that the first two elements get positioned differently, so I create another parent that will wrap the elements I want to position in a different way.

```
<div>
   <div>
      <div>My element 1</div>
      <div>My element 2</div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div>My element 3</div>
      <div>My element 4</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you do that, it will solve many problems